# Is it possible to stream an existing gstreamer pipeline through gstrtspserver

Tags: python, gstreamer, rtsp

So I have a full working pipeline done in python that I am currently just dumping into an autovideosrc. I want to be able to stream through RTSP so I've been looking at gstrtspserver but from what I can tell gstrtspserver only uses a gst_parse_launch like function to construct its pipeline, such as this example

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst','1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer','1.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gst, GstRtspServer

Gst.init(None)


mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()

mounts = server.get_mount_points()

factory = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory()
factory.set_launch('( videotestsrc pattern=ball is-live=1 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )')

mounts.add_factory("/test", factory)

server.attach(None)

print("stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test")
mainloop.run()
```

Is there a way to stream an existing pipeline through RTSP?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [gst_rtsp_media_take_pipeline ()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPMedia.html#gst-rtsp-media-take-pipeline), which takes an existing pipeline.
You would have to derive a class from [GstRTSPMediaFactory](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-rtsp-server/html/GstRTSPMediaFactory.html) to return that new GstRTSPMedia type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to derive your own class from GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory and customize the method do_create_element(self, uri) so that it build and returns your own pipeline.